# Reemplazar contenido de un campo en una base de datos MySQL ¿cuál es la manera óptima de hacerlo?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla que almacena unos códigos con un formato que incluye guiones bajos y quiero cambiarlos por barras:
18001_01 => 18001/01, 18115/02 => 18115/02, etc.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL tiene la función [REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html)  que hace precisamente esto:

```
UPDATE tu_tabla 
SET tu_campo = REPLACE(tu_campo, '_', '/')
WHERE tu_campo LIKE '%_%'
```

También se puede utilizar la orden REPLACE para modificar la salida de una consulta sin modificar los datos:

```
SELECT REPLACE(tu_campo, '_', '/')
FROM tu_tabla
WHERE tu_campo LIKE '%_%'
```

La respuesta la encontré en la edición en inglés de SO: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956993/mysql-string-replace

Answer (score 1):

Cambia "nombre_tabla" y "campo" por aquel que coincida con los tuyos:

```
UPDATE nombre_tabla SET campo = REPLACE(campo, '_', '/');
```

En el caso que quieras que **no** se haga en todos los valores de ese campo, sólo tienes que poner una condición WHERE.

---

Más info de la función [REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html)